# why am not able to resolve my website with 'www' as prefix to the domain name?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx

I am using AWS ROUTE 53 to resolve my website domain name. I am able to launch my website with domain name (domain_name.com). However, when I prefix 'www' to the domain name, its opening only the default nginx page

[image]

My ROUTE 53 configuration:

[image]

MY nginx configuration:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.schoolnskill.com, schoolnskill.com;


        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location /static/ {
        root <path_to_my_django_project>;
        }

        location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:<path_to>/gunicorn.sock;
        #proxy_pass http://unix:<path_to>/gunicorn.sock
    }
}
```

Comment: Then nginx is not configured to recognize both names.

Comment: Can you post your nginx settings?

Comment: ok, I have updated with the current configuration of the nginx.

Comment: I followed https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04 to configure my web server

Comment: Can you remove comma in the server_name, and restart nginx and try?

Comment: @Marcin, removed the comma between schoolnskill.com and www.schoolnskill.com. But nothing changed. Restarted the nginx service as well.

Comment: I just checked, and it works. Maybe you have to remove your browser cache. Seems the comma was the issue.

Comment: Volla, deleted cache, and now it works, thanks for all help

Comment: one last question, does AWS charges for elastic IP?

Comment: Glad to hear. If you don't mind, I will make an answer. EIPs are free for as long as they are attached to running instances.

Comment: @Marcin, Thank you for your reply. You were a great help to my on-going issues.

Comment: @user3521180 No problem :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

Both http://schoolnskill.com/ and http://www.schoolnskill.com/ **work now**, after fixing the  `server_name`. The issue was caused by **comma** in:

```
server_name www.schoolnskill.com, schoolnskill.com;
```

Removing the comma was the solution:

```
server_name www.schoolnskill.com schoolnskill.com;
```